# PDOException Change of message

Tags: php, pdo, phpmyadmin

Good afternoon, I am doing a CRUD, and I am giving the final remarks for its completion, as the subject is, for example if in one of the tables we put a duplicate PK throws this error by the PDOException:

```
SQLSTATE: 23000 (ER_DUP_KEY)
```

But of course, I would like to know if there is any way to modify that message. I see that it is a duplicate primary key, but for example a user who has not seen anything in his life of BBDD can not, I do not know if I explain, I know that if I put an `echo` on it, There is always going to be that mistake there may be others.

This would be the construction towards the BBDD

```
public function __CONSTRUCT() {
    try {
        $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba;charset=UTF8', 'root', '');
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        $this->pdo->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8';");
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

And this for example the insert function:

```
public function Registrar(Categoria $data) {
    try {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO categoria (acronimo,categoria,registro_calidad)
            VALUES (?, ?,?)";
//Ejecucion de la consulta siguiente
        $this->pdo->prepare($sql)->execute(array(
            $data->__GET('acronimo'),
            $data->__GET('categoria'),
            $data->__GET('registro_calidad')
                )
        );
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Thx for Help

Comment: You should never ever change a database error. Let alone it should be never shown to the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider mapping out all errors from the `PDOException`... for example:

```
function outputPDOerror($errorCode = 0) {
  $errors = [
    '23000' => "Error: Duplicate Key",
    '23001' => "Error: Some other error"
  ];

  return array_key_exists($errorCode, $errors) ? $errors[$errorCode] : 'Unknown Error!';
}
```

Then in your try/catch block:

```
catch (PDOException $e) {
  die(outputPDOerror($e->getCode()));
}
```

Comment: +1 @HalfCrazed mapping its perfect for my CRUD, now I can map (although it will take a long time) but that will make all users can understand the errors that the genres of mysql, many thanks for your help.

Comment: @alberto this is an awful suggestion, for too many reasons

Comment: Of course you wouldn't typically reveal DB errors, but there are rare use cases when it's necessary. This is a very rough example in hopes to help get him started and explore other solutions.